Getting the ID and Access Token values in Oracle Apex app after passing OpenID connect SSO against 3rd party Identity Provider
I use Oracle Apex 24.1.0. Configured app, web credentials and authentication scheme to use custom 3rd party Identity Server. It works as expected, I see the "Access Tokens" and "ID Tokens" counter increment in Workspace Utilities -> Web Credentials -> Create/Edit
Problem: my ID token contains user's permissions. I need to grab them. Ideally - programmatically, using PLSQL. Have no idea how to that and if it is possible.
I've seen many examples how people parse tokens using apex_json, but it is not clear how exactly I can grab token after login. I've seen apex_jwt usage to encode / decode tokens, but I've seen no examples how to grab tokens after log in.
Please post a script fragment if you know how to achieve the goal.
